# Iframe no scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I cant seem to show the scrollbar in my iframe. I am making a script that will rotate a page 180 degrees and it uses iframes. With this code it showed no scrollbar.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="browser" src="http://google.com/"></iframe>
```

It loads dynamically(although this is after a button is pressed) but this doesnt change anything.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function refresh()
{ 
    document.getElementById("browser").src = document.getElementById("url").value;  
    document.getElementById("browser").style.visibility="visible"; 
}
function hide()
{
    window.location = "?hide&url="+document.getElementById("url").value; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 26, character 19

Comment: >    <script language="javascript">
function refresh(){
   document.getElementById("browser").src = document.getElementById("url").value;
   document.getElementById("browser").style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide(){
   window.location = "?hide&url="+document.getElementById("url").value;
}
</script>


and 


>    <iframe frameborder="0" id="browser" src="http://google.com/"></iframe>

Comment: I added your code to the question.  In future you can do this yourself using the **Edit** link just below the tags/above the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. The 180 degree rotation removes some parts of html like scrollbars and flash.